# Google API access_type offline not working with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, gmail-api

I'm using gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'
I cannot get a refresh token using offline access. I have two questions:
1. Why can't I get it to work:
The controller that initiates the authorization request is the show action:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @login_url = get_gmail_authorize_url
  if session.has_key?(:access_token)
    @user.update_attributes(
      gmail_access_token: session[:access_token]
      )
  end
end
```

I created a method in a helper file to get the authorization URL:

```
def get_gmail_authorize_url
  client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(... path)
  auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
  auth_client.update!(
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3001/authorize',
    :additional_parameters => {"access_type" => "offline", "approval_prompt" => "force"}
  )
  login_url = auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s
end
```

But when I click the link it redirects to gmail asking for permission to "Manage drafts and send emails" but NOT to get offline access. No refresh token is then passed with the code.

For the callback action I have:

```
def gettoken
  client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(... path)
  auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
  auth_client.update!(
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3001/authorize'
  )
  if request['code'] == nil
    auth_uri = auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s
    redirect_to auth_uri
  else
    auth_client.code = request['code']
    response = auth_client.fetch_access_token!
    session[:access_token] = response['access_token']
    redirect_to user_path(id: session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

When I add this:

```
auth_client.update!(
  ...
  :additional_parameters => {"access_type" => "offline", "approval_prompt" => "force"}
)
```

to the gettoken action, I get `Authorization failed. Server message: { "error" : "invalid_request", "error_description" : "Parameter not allowed for this message type: access_type" }`after permitting the app in gettoken :/

2. Isn't creating two different OAuth::Client a bit redundant? I understand the object is not saved and lost when redirecting, but is there no way to save it?

### Update

Here is a screenshot of the authorization dialog. You can see access_type=offline in the url [image: Google Authorization Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by updating to https://mail.google.com/ in the original call. Still not sure what was happening, but right now I'm not worrying about it.

```
auth_client.update!(
  scope: 'https://mail.google.com/',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3001/authorize',
  :additional_parameters => {
    "access_type" => "offline",
    "include_granted_scopes" => "true"
  }
)
```